# Implement HTML like template in PUG

Tags: express, pug, ejs

I am trying to implement html like template in pug with

```
#{name}
```

but this is not working it double prints it then I use pipeline character

```
|#{name}
```

but its output is  `&lt;h1&gt;This Is Content&lt;h1&gt`
my full template is

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  SomeRandomStuff
</head>
<body>
  |#{Content}
</body>
Scripts
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be text encoding issue, can you share the picture of what the text should be?

Comment: Try adding this

`html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")`

to the top of the file

Answer (score 1):

Use `!{name}` instead.

```js
<html lang="en">
<head>
  SomeRandomStuff
</head>
<body>
  !{Content}
</body>
Scripts
</html>
```

[See docs here.](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped)